# Wildcard SSL and Apache configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, tomcat

I'm pulling my hard on this configuration, which probably is simply. I have a wildcard ssl certificate which is working. I have the website setup to run on domain.com under SSL.

Now, I'm in need to run many subdomains (*.domain.com) on the same server with the same SSL certificate. Shouldn't be that hard, right? Well, I can't get it going.

Point is, that the first config is another Tomcat server that serves another site and listens to domain.com and www.domain.com. The other config listens to *.domain.com and pulls the content from another Tomcat server.

I already tried this whole setup with mod_rewrite, but simply don't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help very much appreciated.

Here is my conf in Apache 2.2:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile ...
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
        SSLCertificateChainFile ...
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com

        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8010/
        ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8010/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile ...
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
        SSLCertificateChainFile ...
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias *.domain.com

        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
        ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?  Are you getting a browser certificate check error?  If so, post the details of that message.  It usually shows why the check failed.  (eg:  Cert for foo.domain.com, actual domain:  bar.domain.com)

Comment: I somehow did not get an notify eMail to your reply...

Comment: What is going wrong is that the SSL cert is working fine, but I can either have *.domain.com working and not www.domain.com (which points to another server) or vice-versa.

Comment: In the meantime, I could get it to work 90%, that means that I can forward https requests to the wildcard domain (*.domain.com) but since it is under another documentroot, images, css, etc. don't really work. This is how I could it get to work

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(www)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1 [P,L]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. Was an issue that my Apache 2.2 did not have VirtualHostName *:443 set. Apache did only set this for port 80.

For Ubuntu users this is in the ports.conf file!